# Understanding PatternTest inside Position

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, warning-messages

I have a list of n dimensional vectors (n=3 in this example). I want to find the position of all vectors for which all elements other than the $i^{th}$ element are equal to some value (2 in this example) and the value of the $i^{th}$ element is not restricted. I've been using the following approach: Create a pattern test that, when applied to a vector (i) deletes the ith element, (ii) deletes duplicates from the remaining elements, and (iii) checks whether the remaining list of non-duplicates is equal to `{2}`.

```
points = {{0, 1, 2}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}};
Position[points, _?(DeleteDuplicates[Delete[#, 2]] == {2} &),{1}]
```

This approach works, but in the process I see several of the following messages:

> Part 2 of List does not exist

Just to make sure my pattern test function is working, I tried

```
(DeleteDuplicates[Delete[#, 2]] == {2} &) /@ points
(*{False, True, True, False}*)
```

The messages go away if I change my pattern test by including `List` immediately after the underscore:

```
Position[points, _List?(DeleteDuplicates[Delete[#, 2]] == {2} &),{1}]
```

As I am already providing a level specification, why is the `_List` necessary to avoid these messages? What is happening when `_List` is not included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position) looks at [`Heads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads) as well by default:

```
points = {{0, 1, 2}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}};
Position[points, _?(DeleteDuplicates[Delete[#, 2]] == {2} &),{1}, Heads->False]
```

> {{2}, {3}}

You could debug this by using [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint):

```
TracePrint[
    Position[points, _?(DeleteDuplicates[Delete[#,2]]=={2}&), {1}],
    _DeleteDuplicates
]
```

> DeleteDuplicates[Delete[List,2]]
>
> Delete::partw: Part 2 of List does not exist.
>
> Delete::partw: Part 2 of List does not exist.
>
> DeleteDuplicates[Delete[{0,1,2},2]]
>
> DeleteDuplicates[{0,2}]
>
> DeleteDuplicates[Delete[{2,4,2},2]]
>
> DeleteDuplicates[{2,2}]
>
> DeleteDuplicates[Delete[{2,1,2},2]]
>
> DeleteDuplicates[{2,2}]
>
> DeleteDuplicates[Delete[{2,3,4},2]]
>
> DeleteDuplicates[{2,4}]
>
> {{2}, {3}}

Notice the `DeleteDuplicates[Delete[List,2]]` output.

Comment: And there it is, in the "details and options" of the documentation. Apologies for missing that before posting. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

```
points = {{0, 1, 2}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}};
check[list_] := DeleteDuplicates[Delete[list, 2]] == {2};
Position[points,Except[List, _?check], {1}]

(* {{2}, {3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Position[points, {a_, _, a_}]
```

> {{2}, {3}}

Comment: Could this approach be easily extended so that it could take, as an argument, the position of the element one wants to ignore? For example,  it would generate `{_,a_,a_}` for argument value `1` and `{a_,a_,_}` for argument value `3`?

Comment: @eldo i realized we can use `OrderlessPatternSequence` in your approach to make it generic i.e. `Position[points, {OrderlessPatternSequence[a_, _, a_]}]`

Comment: You can extend it to `fpos[list_, pos_] := Position[list, Insert[{a_, a_}, Blank[], pos]]`

Comment: @AliHashmi In my case I do care about the order, I just want to use every order separately. Your example led me to discover `Sort[Permutations[{a_,_,a_}]]`, which would do the job. Thanks.

Comment: @eldo That's exactly what I was looking for!